# Do I need an iOS developer license for TestFlight

Tags: ios, cordova

I am going to be creating an iOS app to run on an iPad using the PhoneGap framework.  Instead of putting my app on the App Store I'm going to use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/).  If I'm not going to be using the App Store do I still need to purchase an [iOS developer license](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is mandatory to have a certificate and provisioning profile to build your app for device. You have to enroll for developer program/enterprise developer program if you wish to install your app on a device. It does not matter if you choose to use TestFlight or not.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you need an iOS Developer Account in order to create the provisioning profiles and certificates you need for your app to actually run on a real device.